# Referencing linked css and js resources when returning an html content from an MVC action

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have an MVC controller which has an action which is supposed to render an HTML page.

The HTML of this page is not a part of my MVC page, it is uploaded by the users of the app.

Therefore my controller action looks more or less like that

```
public ActionResult Generate(string pageId)
{
    string htmlFilePath = this.UseSomeLogicToRetrievePathOfHtmlFile(pageId);
    return this.Content(File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath),  "text/html", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

This html file contains referenced resources in the header:

```
   <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <script src="js/utilities.js"></script>
```

These files are located in the same folder as the HTML file (in respective subfolders), however they are not loaded when the page is rendered.

What is the format that this href/src path should have in order to load these resource properly?

Or is there a better way to load & render an html file from within an MVC controller?

Comment: maybe try to use [base url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) in html file

Comment: @yW0K5o - but these .css and .js files are not referenceable via a URL, so not sure how could that work...?

Comment: On rendering the page you can insert `<base>` tag in your HTML. `<body><base href="http://www.example.com/">`. This will update all css/js/img relative URLs to to use base. Try it!

Comment: [W3Schools link is a simple explanation of base tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: @yW0K5o - yes, but these files are just local files on my server...

Comment: I understand that these files are local. Your web page user sees them as not local.

Comment: @yW0K5o, sorry, I must be missing something. So, given that the URL of the controller action is `http://myserver/system/generate/a3f23f` and the html and css files on the server are in the `D:\webapp\pages\a3f23f` folder, how would you structure the base tag href?

Comment: now I see. if I provide base href `http://myserver/system/generate/a3f23f` then css will be at `http://myserver/system/generate/a3f23f\css\main.css` but it is not there. Let me think how to resolve this.

Comment: Try to copy css and js directories from `D:\webapp\pages\a3f23f` to respected paths into `http://myserver/system/generate/a3f23f`. In this case you don't need either HTML files modification or `<base>` tag.